# SQL join with composite primary key

Tags: sql, join, composite, composite-primary-key

I have to join two tables.
But in one table primary key is not there,composite primary key is there,means three columns put together uniquely define a row of that table.
I have those three columns in the other table too.rest nothing is common.
Is there any way to join these two tables.please explain with the help of example

Comment: You don't need a key to join tables. It will just be less efficient.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What problem are you having with joining the tables?

Answer (score 83):

You can use AND in the expression for the ON criteria and demand the fields are all equal there.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Key1 = Table2.Key1 AND Table1.Key2 = Table2.Key2 AND Table1.Key3 = Table2.Key3
```